# Bootstrap gallery: photos with different heights won't line up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

So I'm attempting to make a photo gallery using Bootstrap, and I am stuck for the time being.

First, here is a github link so you can view the site.

http://torgian.github.io/website-dev

Go to the gallery and change the browser width. You can see how the images are different heights, but don't seem to line up properly.

I've spent probably about 7 hours searching and trying different things, to no avail. So I'm finally asking on here.

Currently I'm still learning HTML and CSS, so I haven't touched javascript yet. I would like to find a CSS solution to this, if possible.

What I would like to achieve is something similar to this: http://www.nasarow-fo-to.com/new-gallery

Click on the squares on the lower right and you'll see my gallery pop up: you can see what I am trying to achieve. A nice, even row of thumbnails, 3 or 4 across on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend setting the *height* of all of the images to the same value, and then keeping the `width` style set to `auto`. After this, set the page overflow style to `break-line`, and it should be aligning properly.

An example of how to do this is as follows:

```
body{
    overflow: break-line  //Break the line on content overflow
}
img{
    width: auto;          //Set the width based on the height
    height:10%;           //Set the image hight to 10% of the page
    margin: 20px;         //Set a margin between images
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I used this and it seems to be working well, although I'm still not sure exactly what break-line does.

I will continue to experiment to try to get it perfect, but for now I like this.

Comment: No problem! What `break-line` does is make it so if the content is outside the window, bring it a line down.

Answer (score 0):

you can give spcific width and height to img tag

```html
img{
width:20%;
height:20%;

}
```